# Magento Integration With T-Hub

Tags: php, arrays, magento, quickbooks, sandbox-solution

am setting up a sand box for a T-Hub Integration with Magento and quickbooks.  I've set my life site up locally using WAMP server, and now Its on to trying to tie that local Magento site into T-hub. 
 The first error that I received stated the

*"Connection to Magento store failed. Service authentication failure - Notice: Undefined index: httponly in c:\wamp\www\testsite\appcode\core\mage\Core\Model\Session\Abtract\Varien.php on line 98."*

After some searching I found the the general consensus on that one was I had to put an ssl on my local server, done, that problem's gone. Now I'm get a general error message that simply says

"Connection to Magento Failed"

I used the test page that atandra included with their files which returned this:

```
<RESPONSE Version="4.1">
<Envelope>
<Command>GETORDERS</Command>
<StatusCode>9001</StatusCode>
<StatusMessage>
 Service authentication failure - Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array,      string given in C:\wamp\www\adamsarms\app\code\core\Mage\Captcha\Model\Observer.php on line 166
</StatusMessage>
<Provider>Magento</Provider>
</Envelope>
</RESPONSE>
```

Which kicks back to this is the php file:

```
public function checkUserLoginBackend($observer)
{
    $formId = 'backend_login';
    $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
    $loginParams = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('login', array());
    $login = array_key_exists('username', $loginParams) ? $loginParams['username'] : null;
    if ($captchaModel->isRequired($login)) {
        if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString(Mage::app()->getRequest(), $formId))) {
            $captchaModel->logAttempt($login);
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
        }
    }
    $captchaModel->logAttempt($login);
    return $this;
}
```

This line is the one it directly points to:

```
$login = array_key_exists('username', $loginParams) ? $loginParams['username'] : null;
```

I'm not sure which direction I need to go to fix this error to make t-hub start talking to magento proper, I've included everything that I've got, if someone needs more information please let me know, I just need a better understanding of what might be causing this error to possibly find a path to fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with a Legacy codebase with the T-Hub extension. It was created for PHP 5.3 & Magento versions 1.4 & below. They really should update this thing since people are using it.

The companies official response is this: http://support4.atandra.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/92/4/magento-array_key_exists-error

Which is horrible because it relies on overriding core files.

What's going on is Mage_Captcha_Model_Observer has an event checkUserLoginBackend() that gets fired. This expects the POST info for 'login' to be a certain format. This is something that has changed over the years since legacy code does not have it in this format.

This is a really hacky fix. But it's better than overriding core magento files.
Change the CheckUser() function of Mage/Thub/Model/Run/Run.php to this (I've removed some of their comments):

```
public function CheckUser()
{
    try {
        $username = $this->RequestParams['USERID'];
        $password = $this->RequestParams['PASSWORD'];

        //here we just set the POST to our specified format.. 
        //which is what the observer model thinks it should be
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('login', array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
        ));

        $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/user');
        $userRole = Mage::getSingleton('admin/role');

        if ($user->authenticate($username, $password)) {
            $loadRole = $userRole->load($user->getRoles($user));

        } else {
            print($this->xmlErrorResponse($this->RequestParams['COMMAND'], '9000',
                'Order download service authentication failure - Login/Password supplied did not match', $this->STORE_NAME, ''));
            exit;
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $this->Msg[] = "Critical Error CheckUser (Exception e)=" . $e->getMessage(); //BB 11Nov2014
        print($this->xmlErrorResponse($this->RequestParams['COMMAND'], '9001',
            'Service authentication failure - ' . " " . $e->getMessage(), $this->STORE_NAME, ''));
        // End - <TIBB> 13Dec2011
        exit;
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to extend the Mage_Captcha_Model_Observer class with your own version that removes those array checks in checkUserLoginBackend().